# how to chop off a few decimals of a double value

Tags: c++, double, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [way to get specific integer(s) from a double data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000238/way-to-get-specific-integers-from-a-double-data-type)

**C++**

So i need a way to get say the number 7 from the double 56.279 or any other of the integers and i cannot figure out how to do it without having the knowledge of what the double returned from my function is going to be (so i cant simply do 56.279 - .009).

My function alway **returns seconds elapsed** as a double in this form: 000.000. I also only have 5 character spaces to print the time to the **CONSOLE window** so

if the number is less than ten i need to simply print 0.000 sec, if more than ten 00.00, if more than sixty seconds (one minute) then 0:00, and finally if more than 10 minutes i will print 00:00 in the 5 character space. I need to therefore get rid of the 9 in the 56.279 so the number fits in the space. I'm thinking i need to simply get each number individually except for 9 and insert them into a char array...

Any other ideas?
**Thanks!**

Comment: -1 for posting a duplicate.. and that too, within 35 minutes

Comment: I think the same OP posted the same Q twice and seems like a honest mistake so spare OP the -ve votes.

Comment: Umm I've been editing and re-making the last question as it was too vague, and decided it was different enough to be a new question. Now i'm trying to figure out how to delete this one as i just checked the answers on the other one... SO EVERYONE CALM DOWN.. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this page:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/

If you only need to change the display something like setw might appropriate:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/